# Troubleshooting AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-code-deploy

While running the code pipeline, I got an issue with an error that I can't make a head or tail out of it. How do I troubleshoot it?

[image]

This is my ECS deploy setup
[image]

This is my `buildspec.yml`

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - $(aws ecr get-login --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --no-include-email)
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo copying .htaccess and robots.txt
      - yes | cp -rf config/$XX/.htaccess www/.htaccess
      - yes | cp -rf config/$XX/robots.txt www/robots.txt
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker build -t xx/yy-zz -f Dockerfile.newrelic .
      - docker tag xx/yy-zz:latest 1234.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/xx/yy-zz:latest
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push 1234.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/xx/yy-zz:latest
      - printf '[{"name":"xxx","imageUri":"%s"}]' xxx.dkr.ecr.ap-xx-1.amazonaws.com/xx/yy-zz:latest > imagedefinitions.json

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

Comment: Can you provide the details of how you configured the code-pipeline?

Comment: My source is github, I use code build to build the docker image and push to ECR, and I use the above setup for deploy

Comment: for which action step you are getting the error?

Comment: it is at the code deploy step

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason why. I hit the limit of the Code deploy. It is too big, so I am asking Amazon support to increase it

[image]